# Linked list- Dos error

Tags: c++

I have a list in txt format. I need to create a linked list and put there every data of each row of the file.
I wrote a code, but after I run it, Dos stops working ("the program has stoped working...").
Can anyone tell me where the error is ?

```
    struct node
    {
       string data;
       node *pas;
    };

int main()
{
    struct node *koke;
    struct node *tmp;
    koke = NULL;
    string CH;
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open ("Liste_1.txt~");

    tmp = new node;
    tmp = koke;

    int i=0; 
    while(i<rr) //rr is defined as a constant
    {
       getline(infile,CH);
       tmp->data = CH;
       tmp = tmp->pas;
       i++;
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are u sure you file is `Liste_1.txt~`?

Comment: Yes, the file is named like that. When I do the same thing with an array, everything is OK. It's just about the linked list

Comment: For the record, you probably are not using "Dos", and that is your program that crashed. If you are indeed using "Dos", well, I'm sorry for you :)

Comment: This line looks pretty bad: `tmp = tmp->pas;` Also you're never creating any new nodes inside the loop!!

Comment: Well, I'm wtiting my code on Devc++, so maybe it's him that crashed

Comment: @user3173029 _'so maybe it's him that crashed'_ Very probably not!!!

Comment: @user3173029: More likely, you program crashed (as the message says). That tends to happen when you mess around with pointers like this.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what line caused the crash?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues I have found:

```
tmp = new node;
tmp = koke;
```

Which assignment statement?
You assign a dynamically allocated object to `tmp` then reassign `tmp`, thus losing your dynamically allocated object.

```
while(i<rr) //rr is defined as a constant
{
   getline(infile,CH);
   tmp->data = CH;
   tmp = tmp->pas;
   i++;
}
```

You never allocate another node.  You assign the first value to `tmp`, then move the `tmp` pointer without allocating any new nodes.
BTW, what is the value of `tmp-pas`?  *(A debugger would help you answer this question.)*

Since you are having this much trouble with your own linked list, I recommend you use `std::list` which has already been tested.

Otherwise search StackOverflow for "c++ linked list" for some examples.

**Edit 1 - reading file**
You should not use a constant for the number of lines in a file.  The file is external to your program and cannot be trusted to have the number of lines that you defined in your program.
Search StackOverflow for "c++ end of file" for how to read all the lines in a file, regardless of size.

Answer (score 0):

First you assign `NULL` to `koke`, then you assign `koke` to `tmp` and finally you try to modify `tmp`/`koke` member `data`. Remove `tmp = koke;` and add `tmp->pas = new node;` after `tmp->data = CH;` and it should work (but the code is generally really bad).